# Cal.com Excessive resource consumption

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, next.js

I installed a cal.com on an EC2 instance as instructed here: https://cal.com/docs/introduction/quick-start/self-hosting/installation#requirements

I managed to install it successfully.

When I visit http://localhost:3000 and browse pages it stops responding after some time.

The server is consuming all the available resources. See the below screenshot with 'htop'.

[2 GB Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8msG.png)

**What I have tried

I searched the GitHub issues and could not find a solution

I upgraded the instance (e.g. from 2 GB to 4 GB). The problem still persists. See below image.

[4 GB Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oygFv.png)

Update

I tried to install this locally on my Ubuntu laptop. I am getting the following error.

```
failed to contact turbod. Continuing in standalone mode: connection to turbo daemon process failed. Please ensure the following:
        - the process identified by the pid in the file at /tmp/turbod/e1c068f04a70e6cb/turbod.pid is not running, and remove /tmp/turbod/e1c068f04a70e6cb/turbod.pid
        - check the logs at /root/.local/share/turborepo/logs/e1c068f04a70e6cb-cal.log
        - the unix domain socket at /tmp/turbod/e1c068f04a70e6cb/turbod.sock has been removed
        You can also run without the daemon process by passing --no-daemon
```

What could be the reason for this?